# SQL Query rebuild issue

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions, oracle12c

I inherited this query to rebuild it:

```
SELECT a.poclcdde,
               a.poclnpol,
               a.poclcdce,
               a.poclcdcl,
               a.poclnuor
          FROM dtpocl a
         WHERE     a.poclcdre = '02'
               AND a.poclxope IN ('01', '02')
               AND a.poclnuor =
                      (SELECT MAX (b.poclnuor)
                         FROM dtpocl b
                        WHERE     b.poclcdde = a.poclcdde
                              AND b.poclnpol = a.poclnpol
                              AND b.poclcdce = a.poclcdce
                              AND b.poclcdre = '02'
                              AND b.poclxope IN ('01', '02')
                              AND NVL (b.poclfecb, 99999999) =
                                     (SELECT MAX (NVL (c.poclfecb, 99999999))
                                        FROM dtpocl c
                                       WHERE     c.poclcdde = b.poclcdde
                                             AND c.poclnpol = b.poclnpol
                                             AND c.poclcdce = b.poclcdce
                                             AND c.poclcdre = '02'
                                             AND c.poclxope IN ('01', '02')))
```

I have this Explain Plan:

```
Plan hash value: 94095463

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                    | Name      | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |           |  6293 |   497K|       | 53434   (3)| 00:00:03 |
|   1 |  NESTED LOOPS                |           |       |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS               |           |  6293 |   497K|       | 53434   (3)| 00:00:03 |
|   3 |    VIEW                      | VW_SQ_2   | 12340 |   626K|       | 41045   (4)| 00:00:02 |
|   4 |     HASH GROUP BY            |           | 12340 |   602K|   792K| 41045   (4)| 00:00:02 |
|*  5 |      HASH JOIN               |           | 12340 |   602K|    47M| 40911   (4)| 00:00:02 |
|   6 |       VIEW                   | VW_SQ_1   |  1555K|    29M|       | 23144   (4)| 00:00:01 |
|   7 |        HASH GROUP BY         |           |  1555K|    40M|    65M| 23144   (4)| 00:00:01 |
|*  8 |         TABLE ACCESS FULL    | DTPOCL    |  1555K|    40M|       | 12793   (4)| 00:00:01 |
|*  9 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL      | DTPOCL    |  1555K|    44M|       | 12801   (4)| 00:00:01 |
|* 10 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN          | PK_DTPOCL |     1 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 11 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| DTPOCL    |     1 |    29 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   5 - access("MAX(NVL(C.POCLFECB,99999999))"=NVL("POCLFECB",'99999999') AND 
              "ITEM_1"="POCLCDDE" AND "ITEM_2"="POCLNPOL" AND "ITEM_3"="POCLCDCE")
   8 - filter("POCLCDRE"='02' AND ("POCLXOPE"='01' OR "POCLXOPE"='02'))
   9 - filter("POCLCDRE"='02' AND ("POCLXOPE"='01' OR "POCLXOPE"='02'))
  10 - access("ITEM_4"="POCLCDDE" AND "ITEM_5"="POCLNPOL" AND "ITEM_6"="POCLCDCE" AND 
              "POCLNUOR"="MAX(B.POCLNUOR)")
  11 - filter("POCLCDRE"='02' AND ("POCLXOPE"='01' OR "POCLXOPE"='02'))
```

At first sight, I can imagine that this is a wrong query because: why we need to perform two more sub queries for the same table?
What I need is all the records from `dtpocl` table (with this conditions `a.poclcdre = '02' AND a.poclxope IN ('01', '02')` ) who have the max `poclnuor` and for the max date `poclfecb`.

I've tried to group the two aggregate functions in the same query, like this:

```
SELECT a.poclcdde,
                 a.poclnpol,
                 a.poclcdce,
                 a.poclcdcl,
                 MAX (a.poclnuor),
                 MAX (NVL (a.poclfecb, 99999999))
            FROM dtpocl a
           WHERE a.poclcdre = '02' AND a.poclxope IN ('01', '02')
        GROUP BY a.poclcdde,
                 a.poclnpol,
                 a.poclcdce,
                 a.poclcdcl
```

But I get more records than the original query and with a cost of 25.654. `dtpocl` table have 3.025.510 rows.

What are the tricks that we can do to improve performance and query readability? Thanks.

Comment: Provide sample data and your expected result, which would be easier for others to clear your doubt.

Comment: What column(s) is/are unique for `dtpocl`?

Comment: PK is poclcdde, poclnpol, poclcdce and poclnuor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use analytic functions to find the `poclnuor` that you're interested in.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
(
  SELECT
    dtpocl.*,
    MAX(poclnuor)
      KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY poclfecb DESC NULLS FIRST)
      OVER (PARTITION BY poclcdde, poclnpol, poclcdce)
        AS target_poclnuor
  FROM
    dtpocl
  WHERE
        poclcdre = '02'
    AND poclxope IN ('01', '02')
)
  sorted
WHERE
  poclnuor = target_poclnuor
```

I got the syntax from here...  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions056.htm

You probably want a single index covering `(poclcdde, poclnpol, poclcdce, poclfecb DESC, poclnuor DESC)`

***EDIT:*** OP confirmed PK as `(poclcdde, poclnpol, poclcdce, poclnuor)`

I'm not sure if this is any better, but knowing the PK does mean that this is an alternative...

```
SELECT
  poclcdde,
  poclnpol,
  poclcdce,
  MAX(poclcdcl)
    KEEP (RANK FIRST
          ORDER BY poclfecb DESC NULLS FIRST,
                   poclnuor DESC
    ) 
      AS poclcdcl,
  MAX(poclnuor)
    KEEP (RANK FIRST
          ORDER BY poclfecb DESC NULLS FIRST,
                   poclnuor DESC
    ) 
      AS poclnuor
FROM
  dtpocl
WHERE
      poclcdre = '02'
  AND poclxope IN ('01', '02')
GROUP BY
  poclcdde,
  poclnpol,
  poclcdce
```

Or...

```
SELECT
  sorted.*
FROM
(
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER()
      OVER (PARTITION BY poclcdde, poclnpol, poclcdce
                ORDER BY poclfecb DESC NULLS FIRST,
                         poclnuor DESC
      ) 
        AS seqnum
    dtpocl.*
  FROM
    dtpocl
  WHERE
        poclcdre = '02'
    AND poclxope IN ('01', '02')
) 
  sorted
WHERE
  seqnum = 1
```

Comment: This looks very good. Add `WHERE poclcdre = '02' AND poclxope IN ('01', '02')` to your inner query.

Comment: Thank you guys. But this new query have less cost value (by half) but higher bytes in explain plan. Both queries take the same execution time. Perhaps creating a new index.  But this one, isn't used: `CREATE INDEX testIndex ON dtpocl (poclcdre, poclxope)`

Comment: Did you test all three answers?  How do they compare for you?  Did you try the index I suggest half way through?

Comment: I've tested all three queries. I can see by the Cost in the explain plan. Your query have lower cost than mine. Using a `set timing on´, after the execution of each query, added a ´select count(*) from ´ I get 35 seconds for your query, and 1:23 minute for mine. The optimizer doesn't  use any index of that table. He prefers a full table scan than other thing.

Comment: I will put this solution running in our test environment for performance analysis. But I think we can get better results here. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
-- PK is poclcdde, poclnpol, poclcdce & poclnuor

SELECT a.poclcdde,
       a.poclnpol,
       a.poclcdce,
       a.poclcdcl,
       a.poclnuor,
       a.poclfecb
  FROM dtpocl a
 WHERE a.poclcdre = '02'
   AND a.poclxope IN ('01', '02')
   AND a.poclnuor =
      (SELECT MAX (b.poclnuor)
         FROM dtpocl b
        WHERE b.poclcdde = a.poclcdde 
          AND b.poclnpol = a.poclnpol
          AND b.poclcdce = a.poclcdce
          AND b.poclnuor = a.poclnuor
          AND b.poclcdre = a.poclcdre
          AND b.poclxope = a.poclxope)
   AND NVL (a.poclfecb, 99999999) = -- Here you can only use a.poclfecb and not b.poclfecb
      (SELECT MAX (NVL (c.poclfecb, 99999999))
         FROM dtpocl c
        WHERE c.poclcdde = a.poclcdde 
          AND c.poclnpol = a.poclnpol
          AND c.poclcdce = a.poclcdce
          AND c.poclnuor = a.poclnuor
          AND c.poclcdre = a.poclcdre
          AND c.poclxope = a.poclxope)
```

Comment: Depending in the data, the OP's query can give different results than your query. For example with data `(id, poclfecb, pocnuor)` = `(1, 5, 2), (2, 4, 2)` your query returns only row 1, but the original query returns both rows. *(Without more info it's impossible to tell if this difference matters.)*

Comment: PK is poclcdde, poclnpol & poclcdce and poclnuor

Comment: That difference matters. I get more rows with this solution and MatBailie is correct. Note: `b.poclfecb` must be inside the query to `dtpocl b`

Comment: My query is based on your description... _"What I need is all the records from dtpocl table (with this conditions a.poclcdre = '02' AND a.poclxope IN ('01', '02') ) who have the max poclnuor and for the max date poclfecb."_

Comment: I understand Steve, but I can have two rows with the same `poclnuor` and different `poclfecb`

Comment: Then it sounds like you want the max poclfecb for _each_ poclnuor.